SVG <animateMotion> interchangable
I want to animate circle along the path, once in front of object (big circle), and after in the back of the big circle. I've separate the path, and make 2 circle to animate along separated path. But what I want is, after the "front circle" reach the end of its path, it will disappear, and the "back circle" appear and start to animate, then it repeats. I tried "begin", but while waiting to begin, the circle are staying at (0,0) coordinate, and it's not repeating. I'm okay if the solution are using javascript


svg {
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
 border:1px solid black;
}
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 300">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1 {
        fill: #00930e;
      }
      .cls-2 {
        fill: #141414;
      }
      .cls-3 {
        stroke: red;
      }
      .cls-3, .cls-4 {
        fill: none;
        stroke-miterlimit: 10;
      }
      .cls-5 {
        fill: blue;
      }
      .cls-6 {
        fill: green;
      }
      .cls-4 {
        stroke: #ffe600;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <!--  CIRCLE 2 BACK -->
    <circle class="cls-5" r="9.73">
      <animateMotion
        dur="5s"
        repeatCount="indefinite"
        path="M283.37,129.63c-9.64-26.65-77.18-26.64-150.85.01C58.85,156.3,6.95,199.52,16.6,226.17" />
    </circle>
  <path 
      stroke="yellow"
        fill="none"
        d="M283.37,129.63c-9.64-26.65-77.18-26.64-150.85.01C58.85,156.3,6.95,199.52,16.6,226.17"
        stroke-width="3"
        />
  <!--  CIRCLE 1 BACK  -->
  <circle class="cls-6" r="9.73" >
    <animateMotion
      dur="5s"
      repeatCount="indefinite"
      path="M34.78,59.23c18.61-21.38,81.6,3,140.68,54.44,59.08,51.44,91.89,110.48,73.28,131.85" />
  </circle>
  <path 
      stroke="yellow"
        fill="none"
        d="M34.78,59.23c18.61-21.38,81.6,3,140.68,54.44,59.08,51.44,91.89,110.48,73.28,131.85"
        stroke-width="3"
        />
  
  <!--  BIG CIRCLE  -->
  <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="110" fill="hotpink"/>
  
  <!--  CIRCLE 1 FRONT -->
  <circle class="cls-6" r="9.73" >
    <animateMotion
      dur="5s"
      repeatCount="indefinite"
      path="M248.74,245.53c-18.61,21.38-81.6-3-140.68-54.44C48.97,139.64,16.17,80.61,34.78,59.23" />
  </circle>
  <path 
      stroke="red"
        fill="none"
        d="M248.74,245.53c-18.61,21.38-81.6-3-140.68-54.44C48.97,139.64,16.17,80.61,34.78,59.23"
        stroke-width="3"
        />
  
    <!--  CIRCLE 2 FRONT -->
    <circle class="cls-5" r="9.73">
      <animateMotion
        dur="5s"
        repeatCount="indefinite"
        path="M16.6,226.17c9.64,26.65,77.18,26.64,150.85-.01,73.67-26.66,125.57-69.87,115.92-96.52" />
    </circle>
  <path 
      stroke="red"
        fill="none"
        d="M16.6,226.17c9.64,26.65,77.18,26.64,150.85-.01,73.67-26.66,125.57-69.87,115.92-96.52"
        stroke-width="3"
        />

</svg>



